# Insert form data into the csv file line by line in php

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I am trying to insert the form data into the csv file i.e.. line by line but the problem is appending the data one after the other but the data is inserting in the same line of the csv file.

This is HTML form :

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="insert.php">
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td width="30"><span>First Name</span></td>
            <td width="30"><input type="text" name="fn" id="fn" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="30"><span>Last Name</span></td>
            <td colspan="3"><input name="ln" type="text" id="ln" size="50" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="71">Address</td>
            <td width="10"><input class="" name="address" type="text" id="address" size="100" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td></td>
            <div align="center">
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
            <input type="reset" name="Reset" id="button" value="Reset" />
            </td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is php program :

```
<?php

$first=$_POST["fn"];
$last=$_POST["ln"];
$address=$_POST["address"];

echo "$first <br> $last <br> $address";

if(!empty($first) || !empty($last) || !empty($address)){

$cvsData = $first . "," . $last . "," . $address ;

$fp = fopen("formdata.csv","a"); // $fp is now the file pointer to file $filename

    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp,$cvsData)"; // Write information to the file
        fclose($fp); // Close the file
    } 
}
?>
```

for the first time i inserted details : **abcd , efgh, ijkl**
for the second time also when i inserted details : **abcd , efgh, ijkl**

and the problem is in csv file the **first line is excluding** and second time i am inserting the data **appending in the same line** . which is shown in below snapshot : pleas find .
[image]

New file attached : 
It is not updated when i add :  fwrite($fp,$cvsData . "\n ");
please find the snapshot : 
[image]

Comment: You could give a look at `fputcsv` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the newline. You want:

```
fwrite($fp,$cvsData."\n")
```

Comment: Not able to insert the data in the new line

Comment: and also it is showing the warning message : Warning: fopen(formdata.csv) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\PORTAL\xampp\htdocs\get_insert_csv\insert.php on line 13

Comment: yah, sorry my mistake the file is already open and i am trying to open again thats why it is showing error . and now please tell me the first line is excluding why ?

Comment: The "\n" is a 'newline' (also known as linefeed or LF), and it tells the computer to start writing on the next line. However, it is specifically the unix newline - windows and macs might also use the carriage return (CR or "\r"). Summary: Old macs use "\r", linux uses "\n", and windows uses "\r\n".

Comment: yes , i am using the Windows its working fine when i add : fwrite($fp,$cvsData . "\r\n");    Thanks @Benubird

Comment: Try deleting the csv file to remove the blank first line, it will create it again and should start from the top of the file

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if(!empty($first) || !empty($last) || !empty($address)){

$cvsData = $first . "," . $last . "," . $address  . "\n"; // Add newline

$fp = fopen("formdata.csv","a"); // $fp is now the file pointer to file $filename

    if($fp)
    {
        fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file
        fclose($fp); // Close the file
    }
}
```

Also, you have a syntax error at `fwrite($fp,$cvsData)"; // Write information to the file`

It should be `fwrite($fp,$cvsData); // Write information to the file`

Comment: yes, i done it , but the first line is excluding and inserting the data in the new line only

Answer (score 0):

Add `\n` in `$cvsData`:

```
$cvsData = "\n" . $first . "," . $last . "," . $address ;
```